# StartSession Middleware throwing ErrorException

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5, middleware

Using Laravel 5.2.

I am getting the following error when navigating to a route.

`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::addCookieToResponse() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, null given, called in /Users/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php on line 72 and defined`

**What I don't understand is that if the request is made via `POST`, no ErrorException is thrown and the expected response is received.**

I have modified the `App\Exceptions\Handler::handler($request, Exception $e)` method to the following;

```
public function render($request, Exception $e) {

    // If request is being made via AJAX or wants a JSON response.
    if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {

        // Check to see if 'getStatusCode()' method exists, otherwise use 500.
        $status_code = method_exists($e, 'getStatusCode') ? $e->getStatusCode() : 500;

        // Send JSON response.
         return json($e->getMessage(), $status_code);

    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);

}
```

The `json()` helper is defined as:

```
function json($message, $status = 200, $data = null) {

    $output = [
        'success' => is_between($status, [200, 299]),
        'statusCode' => $status,
        'timestamp' => time(),
        'message' => $message,
    ];

    if(!is_null($data))
        $output['data'] = $data;

    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($output, $status);

}
```

and `is_between()`;

```
function is_between($value, array $range) {

    if($value > $range[1])
        return false;

    if($value < $range[0])
        return false;

    return true;

}
```

I have tried reverting `App\Exceptions\Handler::handler($request, Exception $e)` method back to see if any of  that could be causing an issue, but I still get the same problem.

I have also tried rewriting the routes and the controller, with the same end result, works if made via a `POST` request, otherwise an `ErrorException` is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the framework is not converting the returned string into a response object. The addCookieToResponse method in the Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession class is wanting a Response object as the first param. Make sure that you return one in all of your routes.

Here's a possible quick fix, change it to fit your case.

Before:

```
Route::get('hi', function() {
    return 'hi';
});
```

After:

```
Route::get('hi', function() {
    return response('hi');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have already seen this response scattered around the web, it was one of the first things I tried and it doesn't work. As you can see in the `json()` helper, it is returning a Response object, whether I use the `Response::json($message, $status)` method or the `response()` helper the problem is the same.